# Run callback with correct *this* value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, parent-child

I have a parent component that is named `Subscribe`. It expose a function named `updateProp` (showed below) that is then called from a child component named `SubscribeStep1`. **This function, include a callback as a paremeter**.

The problem is the following, from `SubscribeStep1` to `Subscribe`, I want to send to the function `updateProp`, a callback which have to **modify the state** of the parent component (remember, child component is `SubscribeStep1`, and parent is `Subscribe`). But I have a problem with the **context**, so what I am writing is not working.

The implementation of `updateProp` on `Subscribe`:

```
updateProp = (property, value, callback) => {
const { user } = this.props;

Meteor.call(
  'pendingSubscription.updateProp',
  user.pendingSubscription._id,
  property,
  value || null,
  () => {
    if (callback) {
      callback(); //Here, the execution of the callback that is giving me problems.
    }
  },
 );
};
```

What I am trying to do on `SubscribeStep1`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {updateProp} = this.props;
  updateProp('step', 1, () =>{ //Here, the content of the callback that is giving me problems 
    this.setState({
      step: 1
    })
  });
}
```

**What is the correct way to write the callback?**

Comment: Have you tried debugging, ie finding out what `this` is in the callback? From what I gather, it should work fine...

Comment: @Li357, if I write updateProp('step', 1, () =>{
      console.log('this:', this);
      this.setState({
        step: 1
      })
    });, when it is executed I have in the console: this: SubscribeStep1 {props: {…},

So this refers to SubscribeStep1 (child component). Not to the parent component like I need.

Comment: Oh I thought that was what you wanted. Then just move the updateProp code in componentDidMount from child to the parent into some function (say `foo`). Then add a new prop to your child, say `onMount`. Pass `foo` as the `onMount` prop and call `onMount` in the child in componentDidMount.

Comment: This setup is kind of weird. The child component should not directly update the state of the parent component. Otherwise the child component needs to know what kind of state the parent component has, which breaks component boundaries.

Comment: Also provide the jsx where you are including the child component and sending "updateProp" as props. The availability of correct "this" depends a lot on how you have sent the "updateProp" method as props.